# easy proof of the completeness theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

The completeness theorem of first-order logic states:

*If $\Phi\models\phi$, then $\Phi\vdash\phi$.*

Assume that I have a calculus $\vdash$ in mind for which I want to prove this completeness theorem. What properties should this calculus have?

Can you sketch the idea how to prove the completeness theorem?

Comment: You can see any math log textbook.

Comment: Are we assuming that the logic you have in mind is finitary, first-order logic? Because if you start going too far afield of this framework the answers can become far from simple.

Comment: If you are still concerned with the empty domain, in E.Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA146) (6th ed 2015), **Ch.2.16 Quantification Theory Allowing Empty Domains**, page 146, you can find a calculus that is proved complete for a "suitable" semantics.